# PHP eats a lot of memory on IIS

Tags: windows, php, iis, fastcgi

I just transferred one site from Linux to Windows and I'm getting strange fatal error messages.
My Linux PHP had a 256MB memory limit and never had a single "out of memory" fatal error.

Now on IIS I have the same memory limit but I'm receiving too many

```
PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32508940 bytes) in C:\...\functions.php on line 0
```

I tried to increase (400MB) to see what will happened and this is what I got

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 419430400 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 65013862 bytes) in C:\....\dbfunctions.php on line 1073741824
```

Strange, it's the same application, same memory limit settings..
Also strange is that 2nd error says "on line 1073741824" but wow, that file has 500 lines. 
Is this a Windows/IIS/PHP problem?

My config:
IIS 8.0, PHP 5.3.28, PHP handler php-cgi.exe

Comment: What version of IIS and Windows?

Comment: iis 8.0, windows 2012 standard

Answer (score 4):

## Windows Cache Extension for PHP

There seem to be a plethora of issues that revolve around the windows cache extension for PHP which sets hard memory limits for php.

[Microsoft IIS.net Article](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-on-iis/use-the-windows-cache-extension-for-php)

There are examples and blog posts where removing wincache solves the issue but this may have a detrimental affect on performance of the site.

[An Example of issues related to wincache that sound similar](http://forums.iis.net/t/1174256.aspx)

## Managing PHP Memory in IIS

- `php.ini` - located in the root folder.  Edit in TextPad and change the value for momory_limit.  if 4M is not enough up to 8M, etc.
- In `admin.php` (if your error is in here) add a memory limit line after `ini_set 'memory_limit', '12M'`   if 12MB of memory is what you're looking to add
- You can add a line to `.htaccess`: `php_value memory_limit 32M`
- `wp-config.php` can control memory. You put a line in that looks like this

  `define('WP_MEMORY_LIMIT', '32M');`

Information pulled from phpbb.com and technet.microsoft.com

Comment: Tried to disable wincache, restarted iis, confirmed in phpinfo but still fastcgi process is eating all memory limit and tthrow this error...

Comment: How is `.htaccess` relevant for IIS if not through Helicon Ape? http://superuser.com/questions/800261/using-htaccess-with-iis